# Odd USB Hub + USB to UART Behavior

Tags: usb, uart, esp8266, usb-hub

I've condensensed several USB connections into 1 leveraging the FE1.1s. I built an eval board that tests this setup prior to implementing into the bigger project (see attached schematic).
The FE1.1s feeds 2 devices that support USB data lines (+/-) and 2 UART based devices via the CP2101N IC (I've also built a clone using the FT231X).

The ICs that have the USB lines work just fine (GPS chip and STM32).

Both UART based circuits involve an ESP IC.
The main way of testing this circuit is via the ESPTool, flashing a firmware, which leverages an auto-program circuit.

When hooking up the board to computer A, the FE1.1s shows up as a Generic Hub, which is fine. Also, the CP2101N shows up as a COM port. No issues there.

When I run my `esptool.exe` script to flash the firmware, it does acknowledge that it's in program mode as it shows it has detected the ESP IC. So this confirms the auto-programmer circuit works and it's reading data (IC type, MAC address, etc).

When it starts to load the firmware, it shows an error indicating it is having issues writing (writing timeout).

To troubleshoot, I removed the FE1.1s, and jumpered the USB data (+/-) traces from the USB connection directly to the traces of the CP2101N. Everything worked perfectly in this case.
To make things more interesting, with everything connected as is from the schematic attached (e.g no STM32), connecting it to computer B, the esptool works when hooked directly to the computer's USB port (both USB 3.2 and USB 2.0 ports). It doesn't work when connected through a USB hub on compter B however. I have tried different baud rates - makes no difference.

In all cases, reading seems fine since it can always read the ESP IC ( IC type, mac address, etc). In all cases, the USB devices (Hub and UART) show up in device manage as working - no indication it's failing.

It's a 2 layer board with 90ohm co-planar differential setup for the USB lines. Ground pours on top and bottom layers.

I've seen some schematics where the TX (CP2101 side) to the RX (ESP side) has a 1k resistor between the two. Not entirely sure the purpose of that, but as I'm having write issue, figured it might be something to explore?

I have questions that may reveal what the issue may be:

1. Why does it seem like this setup is picky about what it's being connected to and it's ability to write? Works on some computers, not others. Simarily, why do writes fail when connect through a USB hub on the computer where it works when connected direclty?
2. Why did bypassing the FE1.1 work on the computer that otherwise failed with writes?

As mentioned above, I've made of clone of this schematic, but used a FT231X instead of the CP2101. It behaves similarly as the CP2101 - works on one machine, not the other; bypassing the FE1.1s works, etc...

[image: schematic]
[image: esptool error]

Comment: So you are powering many chips from a single USB connector, from a PC? How much the chips consume current in total, and how much the PC can provide? Is it connected to generic USB2 port, generic USB3 port, Type-C port, battery charging port, or where? Also, 90 ohms differential on a 2 layer board? Either  your PCB is extremely thing or the USB data traces are extremely wide, or the impedance isn't 90 ohms. Care to post the PCB layout or calculations for trace width?

Comment: The ESP8266 draws up to 300mA when trasmitting Wifi. The 3.3v LDO that feeds the Wifi chip is 500mA rated. In my tests with no wifi activity, I'm sure it's closer to 100mA or less. The CP2102 and FE1.1 ICs are dozens of mA of current perhaps. Not sure it's a lack of power issue. 
In Altium, for 90ohm diff coplanar, its 11.8mil traces, 5mil gutter, and 7.8mil side clearance for a standard 62mil board. If traces were an issue, I'd imagine the longer runs to the devices that take USB data lines directly would be affected as well?